# using php script in task scheduler on window 7

Tags: php, windows, cron

**INDEX.PHP**

```
<?php
include "config.php";
$i=1;
$r=mysql_query(" INSERT INTO test1 (score) VALUES ('$i'); ") or die("not done");
?>
```

I am trying to use **cron job** in **window 7** . I have written a php script in which I am inserting the `$i` values . Using a **task scheduler** , I have created a task in which after 1 Min `$i`  value is going to insert

In the **actions** column of **task scheduler** , I am using this path

> C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f C:\xampp\htdocs\corn\index.php

but when I run this task , a command prompt type window open ie taskeng.exe and it closes after few seconds but my database shows no changes ie no value is inserting . please can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong ??

Comment: Any info from PHP error log?

Comment: nope , it just show the empty command prompt ie taskeng.exe

Comment: I mean PHP error log file, not the output of the script. Plus, you can directly run this command in cmd and see if there's something wrong.

Comment: @Passerby please can you explain me by using task scheduler ......i have never used task scheduler to run the php script

Comment: This does not have too much to do with Windows task scheduler; I believe it's your script and the script's working path that matters. You can 1) look at the PHP error log file; or 2) run your script in command line at `c:\xampp\php` as to simulate the situation when run from scheduled task.

Comment: @Passerby now its showing me NOT DONE

Comment: Change `include("config.php")` to `include(__DIR__.'\config.php')` (and possibly all includes inside `config.php` and the chain) and try again.