# cron scheduler for php

Tags: php, cron

I have this code and I want to add my code with cron scheduler so tell me the process to add my code with cron. I want to generate automatic emails with the help of corn or this code. I am using this for a website to generate automatically mails in 15 days.

```
<?php
require_once('PHPMailer_v5.1/class.phpmailer.php'); //library added in download source.
    $msg  = 'Hello World';
    $subj = 'test mail message';
    $to   = 'vishwakarmanuj@gmail.com';
    $from = 'example@gmail.com';
    $name = 'My Name';

    echo smtpmailer($to,$from, $name ,$subj, $msg);

    function smtpmailer($to, $from, $from_name = 'Example.com', $subject, $body, $is_gmail = true)
    {
        global $error;
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
        if($is_gmail)
        {
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
            $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
            $mail->Port = 465;  
            $mail->Username = 'example@gmail.com';  
            $mail->Password = '***********';   
        }
        else
        {
            $mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.google.com';
            $mail->Username = 'example@gmail.com';  
            $mail->Password = '**********';
        }
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->From="example1@gmail.com";
        $mail->FromName="anuj.dhiman1@gmail.com";
        $mail->Sender=$from; // indicates ReturnPath header
        $mail->AddReplyTo($from, $from_name); // indicates ReplyTo headers
        $mail->AddCC('ashutoshpandey.in@gmail.com', 'CC: to phpgang.com');
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body = $body;
        $mail->AddAddress($to);
        if(!$mail->Send())
        {
            $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            $error = 'Message sent!';
            return false;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: i dont see what the code has to do with cron

Comment: good job leaving your *emails*, *passwords* and *usernames* in your code... **bravo**

Comment: you want to set up a cron job?

Comment: @Jakub: I tried editing to hide them, but there are other edits pending so it won't let me submit.

To the Poster: Please replace the email addresses and passwords with non-real-world examples. It would also be wise to change the password on the potentially compromised account ASAP.

Comment: @Jakun DOn't worry Gmail provides security in case someone else tries to barge in. In my case SMS alerts saved me once.

Comment: I'm not worried, just pointing out that the OP is stupid for posting credentials that can be USED FOR SMTP, or accessing say, an itunes account or banking info if tried / guessed... lol

Comment: @user3184279 : Carefully change your credentials. I hope your edit reflect soon

Answer (score 1):

You will need to configure the cron on the server. This usually requires SSH or similar access, and is usually done from the command line using a program such as Putty. However, depending on your hosting setup, you may be able to update it using a CPanel cron scheduler or other user friendly tools. I'd recommend contacting your hosting provider if you are not familiar with managing cron schedulers on your own.

Instructions on setting up scripts to run on cron on Linux are covered here:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

Quote: To edit your crontab file, type the following command at the UNIX / Linux shell prompt:
    $ crontab -e

You can then add entries to the cron file for individual scripts:

```
1 2 3 4 5 /root/path/to/script.php
```

Where,

```
1: Minute (0-59)
2: Hours (0-23)
3: Day (0-31)
4: Month (0-12 [12 == December])
5: Day of the week(0-7 [7 or 0 == sunday])
/path/to/command - Script or command name to schedule
```

As stated in the comment below, you can also run the script "every minute" or "every hour" by replacing the minute or hour numbers with asterisks:

Run script every minute of every hour of every day (script runs every 60 seconds):

```
* * * * * /root/path/to/script.php
```

Run script every hour at the 15th minute of the hour:

```
15 * * * * /root/path/to/script.php
```

Comment: Btw, parts 1-5 can be * to mean 'any'.

Comment: Good comment, see update above for "every minute" and "every hour" examples.

Answer (score 0):

I know two ways you can put PHP scripts in a scheduler so that they are executed periodically, **in your case shooting emails**

1. You can configure the scripts in a windows scheduler =>[using php script in task scheduler on window 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607546/using-php-script-in-task-scheduler-on-window-7)
2. If you are using some hosting that has CPanel (most of the hosting do) you can schedule the jobs in the CPanel as well so that your production server shoots mails periodically. 
   Here are the links that will help you in CPanel. http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/cpanel/cron_jobs.htm
   http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/CronJobs

Happy Scheduling ;)